# 70s or 80s movie with tentacle monster and female main character

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched it when I was a kid, so it must be from 70s or early 80s. Here are what I can remember.

1. A monster (tentacle) rips the face from a man.
2. The main character is a woman.
3. In one of the scene near the end that woman came back to Earth to find out that no one was left alive, and the scene was all red.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)